# Curl command works in terminal but not in Shell script run in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am writing a shell script to download and install my company's MSP agent on new Mac computers that a client of ours is going to purchase.  When I run the following command in the terminal it works perfectly:

```
curl --output AgentInstall.zip <url>
```

however when I put the same exact line in my script it returns the following error on running:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

I'm not doing anything fancy like embedding the command in a variable.  I've tried more variations on this then I can count, different options such as -o, -O, -oO, and others, I've tried using

`$https://<url>`

I've tried wrapping the URL in "", but nothing I have tried has given any sort of success.  The thing that baffles me the most is that the command I posted above works when pasted directly into the terminal, but not the script.  I am brand new to Shell/Bash scripting, so I'm sure it's some newbie thing that I'm missing, but if someone could point out what that is I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

EDIT To include Minimal Reproducible Example:

I have included my script with the URL changed to the Firefox download link.  I have confirmed that once again, the command pasted into the terminal works perfectly but when run in the script it returns the above error.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#download and extract agent
#
mkdir /tmp/AgentInstall
cd /tmp/AgentInstall
curl --output AgentInstall.zip https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/download/thanks/
unzip AgentInstall.zip
#
```

Comment: `<url>` isn't in your line, so it can't be the "exact same" line.

Comment: That said, one possibility is that your script has hidden characters, like DOS line endings.

Comment: Try running `bash -x yourscript`; it if prints the URL like `$'http://example.com/whatever\r'`, with `$'` and `\r'`, you know your file has CRLF newlines instead of valid UNIX LF-only newlines.

Comment: Beyond that, though -- we _really_ need a [mre] to solve this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you have a reason for thinking `$https://<url>` would work, or are you just throwing random shell-like constructs into your script in hopes that something will magically work?

Comment: I didn't want to post the exact URL because it's a direct link to the agent installer, something I didn't want public, however I have copied the line out of my script and pasted it into the terminal and it worked perfectly.

I will look into the newlines thing.

And I was looking at this: https://linuxhint.com/curl_bash_examples/

Which gave the example of `${url}`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes it does return the \r when I run the command.  How do I fix that?  I'm using Notepad++ to write the script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Figured out how to switch from CRLF to LF and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Error was caused by CRLF newlines instead of LF newlines.  Thank you @Charles Duffy for your help!